# How to pass a value from input-text through Jquery Ajax to php function while I type? Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using Wordpress, and here is my html code:

```
<input class="form-control text-right" name="majorhead" required="" type="number" id="majorhead"/> 
<div class="result_majorhead"></div>
```

JS code:

```
<script>
    jQuery("#majorhead").on("keyup",function(){    
        jQuery.get(ajaxurl,{'action': 'majorhead'}, 
             function (msg) { jQuery(".result_majorhead").html(msg);
                   });
      });

</script>
```

Here is my code in function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_majorhead', 'majorhead_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_majorhead', 'majorhead_function');
function majorhead_function(){
  echo 'hello';
  exit();
}
```

For now I am able to display a simple message "Hello" in the same web page whatever I type in the input box. Now I want to display the exact value from the input-text in the display message while typing.

for example: if I type 1, it should display 1 and If  I type another another 2 then it should display 12.

Comment: just use this $('#majorhead').val(); 
and not this jQuery(".result_majorhead").html(msg);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do in your Javascript is:

1. Add "change" event so that you could use the arrows to control the "number" input.
2. Get the value of the input.
3. Add the value to your GET parameters.

   ```
   jQuery("#majorhead").on("keyup change",function(){ 
       var majorhead_value = $(this).val();
       jQuery.get(ajaxurl,{'action': 'majorhead','majorhead_value': majorhead_value}, 
            function (msg) { jQuery(".result_majorhead").html(msg);
       });
   ```

   });

In your PHP script you should display the GET value:

```
function majorhead_function(){
echo $_GET['majorhead_value'];
exit();
}
```

If you have multiple inputs you may process them like this:

```
jQuery("#text1, #text2, #text3").on("keyup change",function(){    
var majorhead_value = parseInt(0+$("#text1").val());
majorhead_value += parseInt(0+$("#text2").val());
majorhead_value += parseInt(0+$("#text3").val());

jQuery.get(ajaxurl,{'action': 'majorhead','majorhead_value': majorhead_value}, 
function (msg) { jQuery(".result_majorhead").html(msg);
});
```

});

I assume that your HTML will look like this:

```
    <input class="form-control text-right" name="text1" required="" type="number" id="text1"/> 
<input class="form-control text-right" name="text2" required="" type="number" id="text2"/> 
<input class="form-control text-right" name="text3" required="" type="number" id="text3"/> 
<div class="result_majorhead"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works! What if I have multiple input-text boxes with ID="text1","text2","text3" and so on.... and how to pass the value of text1 and text2 together in text3?

Comment: I've added an example that calculates the sum of a few inputs.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE**

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Search Service" id="search_service" name="service" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="">
```

**Here is my Ajax Function in function.php**

```
function search_service() {

    $search_ser = $_POST['search_ser'];

    echo $search_ser;

    die();

}

add_action('wp_ajax_search_service', 'search_service');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search_service', 'search_service');
```

**JS Code:**

```
jQuery( "#search_service" ).keyup( function() {

    var search_ser = jQuery(this).val();

    var ajax_url = jQuery('#ajax_url_input').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'search_service',
            search_ser: search_ser,
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
        },
        success:function(data){

            jQuery("._services_list").html(data);

        }
    });

});
```